# Strange suspension issues on macbook pro Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: suspend, hibernate, macbook

I am experiencing issues to get suspension working on my macbook pro with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
The issue depends to a certain extent on whether the thunderbolt-Ethernet adapter is plugged or unplugged (whether the Ethernet cable is plugged or not doesn't seem to change anything)
I can get successful suspension almost only with unplugged adapter, but even in this case it will work only a few times after a reboot. After a few successful attempts, next attempts won't work anymore till a reboot.

To get more insight I tested suspension through the "pause" button with different configurations, mainly without logging in.

There are 4 different configurations :
1 thunderbolt-Ethernet adapter is unplugged
2 adapter is plugged in
3 adapter was plugged during boot and unplugged before attempts to suspend
4 adapter is plugged in only after boot (and therefore before attempts to suspend)

And six states:
A suspension is successful
B suspension seems successful (fan off) but it respawns after one second
C it is only sleeping (fan on) with black screen, it respawns after hitting a key
D it is only sleeping with black screen, and it cannot respawn, it seems frozen
E it is only sleeping with black screen, and it respawns after 1 second without hitting a key
F suspension seems successful (fan off) but it respawns after one second and then seems frozen.

Configuration 1 always leads to state A (OK) at first attempt and sometimes for second, third and fourth firsts attempts, and then next tries lead to state B
Config 2 leads to D (frozen)
Config 3 leads to C at first attempt, and then next tries lead to E
Config 4 first attempt may to lead F (frozen) or to A (OK) and then next attempt leads to B, D or F

Any idea about what is going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Power off / on all during suspend / resume

It's very difficult to isolate what is going on. One good chance of making everything work is with this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Original script was using /bin/sh but shellcheck reporting warnings.

# NAME: custom-xhci_hcd
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# CALL: Called from SystemD automatically
# DESC: Suspend broken for USB3.0 as of Oct 25/2018 various kernels all at once

# DATE: Oct 28 2018.

# NOTE: From comment #61 at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998

TMPLIST=/tmp/xhci-dev-list

# Original script was: case "${1}" in hibernate|suspend)

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
    echo -n '' > $TMPLIST
          for i in `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ | egrep '[0-9a-z]+\:[0-9a-z]+\:.*$'`; do
              # Unbind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
               echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
           echo "$i" >> $TMPLIST
          done
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    for i in `cat $TMPLIST`; do
              # Bind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
              echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
    done
    rm $TMPLIST
        ;;
esac
```

#### Housekeeping

Create the script with root powers:

- `sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd`

Insert text above and save file. Mark script as executable:

- `sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd`

#### Reboot and test

If the script doesn't help remove it with:

- `sudo rm -f /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd`

Comment: Well, although the issue is not *completely* addressed there is big progress. Now I can flawlessly suspend and resume unlimited times, as long the Thunderbolt adapter was not plugged in at boot time and is not plugged in at suspend time (the issue with Thunderbolt seems difficult https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1371159). Another nice difference is that now it resumes with power key instead of any key.